# How can I make image that will be at top of my site scale up or down properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a space at the top of my site where there is an image.

The image is 2800px wide, and 400px height.

I want to have 400px set aside at the top for this image, but since the image is so wide, is there a way to make it fit without making it look blurry?

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

---

```
.bg {
    background: url('..//img/top-img.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: use `background-size:contain;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `.bg`

```
background-size: cover;
```

However this will crop your image when needed

Regarding the blurriness? There's no solution here but to make your image bigger but as I can see, your image is already big enough that making it bigger will make loading slow.